# Unable to get jQuery validation to work

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation, wampserver

I am using php and CodeIgniter. I am a novice at both of these (career VB.Net and C# developer). However, trying to create a basic registration form, I'm having a hard time getting jQuery validation to work.

header.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php if(isset($title)) {?>
            <title>Discuss Cards - <?php echo $title ?></title>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <title>Discuss Cards</title>
        <?php } ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>styles/forum.css" type="text/css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if(isset($title)) {?>
            <h1><?php echo $title?></h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (isset($page_description)) {?>
            <p id="page_description"><?php echo $page_description?></p>
        <?php } ?>
```

create.php

```
        <script>
            $("#createaccount").validate();
        </script>
        <?php $attributes = array('id'=>'createaccount');
                    echo form_open('user/create_account',$attributes); ?>
                <?php echo form_label('Email','txtEmail');?>
                <br />
                <?php $data = array('type'=>'email','name'=>'txtEmail','id'=>'txtEmail','maxlength'=>'50','minlength'=>'2');
                            echo form_input($data); ?>
                <br /><br />
                <?php echo form_label('Username','txtUsername');?>
                <br />
                <?php $data = array('name'=>'txtUsername','id'=>'txtUsername','maxlength'=>'50','minlength'=>'5');
                            echo form_input($data); ?>
                <br /><br />
                <?php echo form_label('Password','pswPassword');?>
                <br />
                <?php $data = array('name'=>'pswPassword','id'=>'pswPassword');
                            echo form_password($data); ?>
                <br /><br />
                <?php echo form_label('Confirm Password','pswConfirmPassword');?>
                <br />
                <?php $data = array('name'=>'pswConfirmPassword','id'=>'pswConfirmPassword');
                            echo form_password($data); ?>
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" name="Register"  />
        <?php echo form_close();?>
```

footer.php

```
        <strong>&copy; 2016</strong>
    </body>
</html>
```

result...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Discuss Cards - Create New Account</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://[::1]/forum/styles/forum.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://[::1]/forum/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Create New Account</h1>
        <script>
            $("#createaccount").validate();
        </script>
        <form action="http://[::1]/forum/index.php/user/create_account" id="createaccount" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="txtEmail" value id="txtEmail" maxlength="50" minlength="2">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="txtUsername"></label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value id="txtUsername" maxlength="50" minlength="5">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="pswPassword">Password</label>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="pswPassword" value id="pswPassword">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="pswConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="pswConfirmPassword" value id="pswConfirmPassword">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="Register">
        </form>
        <strong>© 2016</strong>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the links to the js and css files are correct. I used the example from http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

However, I feel that I'm missing something because it's not working. When I use their demo (http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/), a new label is created under the input area which displays the error. However, when I test my code (Notepadd++, latest version of Google Chrome, WAMPServer 2.5), I only get Chrome validation. Could someone point out to me what I'm doing incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit too long for a comment, but not sure if it is the only problem. The first thing I see is that the

```
<script>
    $("#createaccount").validate();
</script>
```

is located before the form with id="createaccount". This means this javascript code is parsed and run before the element exists inside the DOM.

In order to run this JS when the DOM is loaded, you then need to wrap it into this specific jquery part :

```
$( document ).ready( function( ) {
    $("#createaccount").validate();
}
```

(And ideally you put all JS at the end of the page, before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: That did it. Truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity Great it helped ! You're most welcome.